# Ruby Module NameError -- order matters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

Ruby 1.9.2 p290 and Rails 3.0.9

I have a .rb file structured like this:

```
module M1
  # .... some method defs ...

  # Code in the middle, outside of any def:

  if Rails.version >= '3'
    class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie

      ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do

        ActionController::Base.send :include, ::M1::M2 # <- throws an error..

      end
    end
  end

  module M2
  # ... method defs ...
  end
end
```

The line `ActionController::Base.send :include, ::M1::M2` throws a NameError - it can't find M2.

However, **when I move M2 to the top of M1**, it resolves the reference with no problems. Is this just how Ruby works - the interpreter doesn't do a first pass to get all the valid names in scope? Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Does that errors appear after defining your own controller that are inheriting from ActionController::Base?

Comment: This code is from the open_id_authentication gem (https://github.com/Velir/open_id_authentication), though I changed the names of the modules to make it easier to read. Error happens whenever I try and run the server (rails s)

Comment: As I can see from source, code're defining `on_load` block as `ActionController::Base.send :include, ControllerMethods`, not `ActionController::Base.send :include, ::OpenIdAuthentication::ControllerMethods`. Pls correct me if I wrong

Comment: You're right - I changed it in my local code because the stuff from source wasn't working either; same problem. Going to fork it on github and put in a pull request.. not sure how it's working for anyone at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that Ruby files are read from top to bottom. The bodies of classes are executable code. So the simple reason for the name error is that the Ruby interpreter just hasn't reached that part of the code yet.

So, this is actually perfectly legal Ruby code:

```
class Foo

  puts "hello from inside a class"

end
```

The definition of a class is just another expression. And, just like every expression in Ruby, it has a return value, so the following works:

```
two = class Foo

  def bar
  end

  1 + 1

end
```

It becomes more obvious when you use an alternative syntax for creating classes:

```
Foo = Class.new do
  puts "Hello"
end
```

The only difference is that you do not enter a namespace when you write it this way.

You have already seen this behavior in ActiveRecord:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Here, `has_many` is just a method call that exists on `ActiveRecord::Base`. It will be executed directly when the file is loaded. That's why some of the parameters of `has_many` and other relations are passed in as a string.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
end
```

If you were to mention the class `User` itself, it would raise a `NameError`, because `User` might not be loaded when `Post` is loaded. (this isn't actually the case in Rails, because Rails intercepts NameErrors and tries to find the file needed, but that's besides the point here). The 'definition' of the relation is stored, and only when accessing the relation later on, will the pieces be put together.

Modules are exactly the same in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. When Ruby interprets code and does not know a constant, it raises a name error:

```
class ModuleA
  include ModuleB
end

module ModuleB
end
```

However, if the code gets not run, it won't raise:

```
def some_method
  include ModuleC
end

module ModuleC
end

some_method
```